# Need to run some db scripts using ansible . But the db script is invoking other scripts while executing

Tags: ansible

Copied the script to destination server using copy module. But the script is not executing while using ansible and could able to execute manually in sever end.

the scripts are copied in `/home/oracle/SCRIPTS` in db server
under this directory there exist a script named **test.sql** and a directory named **TEST**.
 The test.sql script is given below:

```
@TEST/TEST_USER.sql
```

and under TEST directory there exist another script (**TEST_USER.sql**) having the below content:

```
CREATE USER TEST
  IDENTIFIED BY password1
  DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS
  TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP
  PROFILE DEFAULT
  ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

and my ansible playbook looks like :

```
  - name: Connecting DB
    shell: sqlplus username/password @/home/oracle/SCRIPTS/test.sql
    environment:
      ORACLE_HOME: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_2
      HOME: /home/oracle
      PATH: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_2/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/oracle/bin
      ORACLE_SID: <SID NAME>
    register: sqlout

  - debug:
     var: sqlout.stdout_lines
```

Any help would be apprecated.
Thank You !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using the shell module, you could use the **chdir** parameter (see http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/shell_module.html)

regards